# Delete python environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017

Python newbie here. I am on windows. I installed anaconda a while back for my own user account (not for all users on windows). It installed into c:\users...\local..anaconda and all is good. I might have recently updated anaconda and installed VS 2017.

Now I seem to have 4 python environments.

I tried uninstalling from add-remove programs but some how the environments did not go away.

[image]

My questions:
 1. Where does Visual Studio get the list of environment names?
 2. How do I delete these environments? I just want to keep one and delete all the others

Answer (score 4):

I deleted the unwanted registry keys from (what solved the problem for me):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore\
```

The source mentions also the following keys, but they did not exist in my computer:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Python\PythonCore\  
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\
```

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/18

Comment: This answer is correct, but it is a bit incomplete. You might also need to go to the directory HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Python\PythonCore\ and delete the keys from there. Values in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER category will overrule values in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE category, but there's a chance that Visual Studio is looking in that machine category.
Also, even these steps might not completely remove the listing from the Python Environment in existing projects, but it will at least crossout that environment entry. That is my experience: 3 are removed entirely, and two are crossed out.

Answer (score 2):

**I found my answer to this question here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#fix-or-delete-invalid-environments**

- First click this button

[image: Click the button here]

- You will then see this kind of screen

[image]

- Then click the dropdown menu *where it shows - packages*. Then click the overview tab.
- Click the delete/remove the enviroment.
- Your enviroment should now be removed.

Comment: I tried that, but I don't see any "Delete/remove environment" from that Overview tab. This is with Visual Studio 2019, Version 16.10.4.

Comment: Unless this answer is skipping a step, it does not say how to remove Python environments. Instead, it just gives the way to delete some of the packages within an environment.

Answer (score 0):

This is [the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/python-environments) to read

I'll quote you what I think is relevant for your case, but if it's not, just read it all and find what you need

> Any global environment can be added as a project environment by
>   right-clicking Python Environments and selecting Add/Remove Python
>   Environments.... From the displayed list you can select or deselect
>   those environments that are available in your project.+

And...

> Once a virtual environment is added to your project, it appears in the
>   Python Environments window, you can activate it like any other
>   environment, and you can manage its packages. Right-clicking it and
>   selecting Remove either removes the reference to the environment, or
>   deletes the environment and all its files on disk (but not the base
>   interpreter).

Answer (score 0):

**to Question 1:**

Visual Studio searches the registry to detect global installed python environments by following [PEP 514](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0514/) as described in [Install Python interpreters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/installing-python-interpreters?view=vs-2017).

**to Question 2:**

Open the *Visual Studio Installer* again and change the current installation by selecting only the python interpreters you need (you will find they in the *Components* tab).